# Actions module not found when deploying through fab.dev?

Tags: deployment, next.js, floating-action-button, cloudflare-workers

I am deploying my next.js app through fab.dev to cloudflare workers and after generating the fab.zip file I'm unable to deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the steps you can try ,

1. Reinstall fab actions module

`npm install @fab/actions`

2. Make sure you are running fab in bash env or any linux env
   it doesnt really work well with windows powershell